# Photoshop script to determine color or black and white photo

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm ALL new to Photoshop-scripting, and I can't seem to find very much documentation on this. I know some Applescript-scripting, but as I've read Photoshop-scripting is mostly like JAVA-scripting?

Anyhoo, I need a script that'll determine whether the active document in Photoshop is a color photo or a black and white photo. I know how I think it'll work, but I don't know how to write it. I need this for a print action I've made to print JPG files. So it is always finished JPG files that this script will run on.

Here's what I'm thinking on the theory to make it work:

1. Duplicate the background layer. (can be done with an action)
2. Add Filter - Blur - Average to the new layer (can be done with an action)
3. If, on the new layer, Red channel equals Blue channel and if Blue channel equals Green channel anywhere on the new layer that'll have the same color and luminosity all over, do 'black and white actions' else do 'color actions'. (i need a script for this)

The thought behind this, as you already figured out, is to make a layer that is measurable anywhere to determine whether or not there is any color in the image. 
This is the best way I can think of, to make a script that'll work on all images (not multilayered images though).

Can anyone help me with this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
#target photoshop

var savePathSH = "Macintosh HD:PATH1:"
var savePathFarve = "Macintosh HD:Users:PATH2:"
var doc = app.activeDocument
var fname = doc.name.split(".jpg")
var fname = fname[0]
var halfHeight = (app.activeDocument.height) / 2;
var halfWidth = (app.activeDocument.width) / 2;
var newLayer = doc.activeLayer.duplicate();

function saveJPG(name, savepath){
var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var file = new File(savepath + name + ".jpg");
var opts = new JPEGSaveOptions();
opts.quality = 12;

doc.saveAs(file, opts, true);
}

newLayer;

doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[0];

doc.activeLayer.applyAverage();

app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll();

var theSampler = app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.add([halfWidth,halfHeight]);

var currentColor = theSampler.color;

var redValue = theSampler.color.rgb.red;
var greenValue = theSampler.color.rgb.green;
var blueValue = theSampler.color.rgb.blue;

app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll();

doc.activeLayer.remove();

if (redValue == greenValue && greenValue == blueValue) {

    var BW = true
    } else {
    var BW = false
    }

    if (BW == true) {
saveJPG(fname, savePathSH);
} else {
saveJPG(fname, savePathFarve);
}
```